# Can't close Django message alerts

Tags: python, django, message, alerts

I know this is something silly but I just can't seem to fix it.

I'm displaying alerts onto a Django template, and would like the user to remove the alert by pressing the 'X' icon that is displayed when it pops up. My issue is that clicking the 'X' icon doesn't work. the alert messages also do not show when redirected to the home page, however when navigating to a product page all the alerts that have been generated for that page will show up at once.

Here is my base template which shows the messages:

```
<body>
    <div class="mt-5 pt-4">
        {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="messages {{ message.tags }} fade show" role="alert">
            {{ message }}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <!-- <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> -->
            </button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</body>
```

And my messages are created in the views.py file when a point in a statement is reached, e.g.:

```
order_item.save()
messages.success(request, 'This item quantity was updated.')

order.items.add(order_item)
messages.success(request, 'This item was added to your cart.')
```

And here is an example of the alert when it pops up.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap 5.x you need ```<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>``` pay attention to the ```data-bs-dismiss="alert"```

Answer (score 1):

use data-bs-dismiss="alert" instead of data-dismiss="alert"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.